# Redirect a Subdomain to a URL

Tags: url, redirect, subdomain

I would like to redirect a subdomain to another URL.

For example, a user visits `https://fun.mydomain.com` and I want to redirect them to `https://google.com/fun`. What's the best way to make this?

I'm a complete beginner at domains and cloud hosting.

Many thanks.